# WebSocket overhead and manually buffering packets

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, sockets, websocket

**Preface:** I know this may be premature optimization. Please ignore that while answering.

I'm working on a whiteboard type program that uses WebSockets where only one person can draw at a time and everyone else in the room can watch the drawing take place.

Currently there are a lot of packets that solely consist of an x and y coordinate that are sent around 40 times a second, depending on how fast they draw.

I'm wondering, first of all, what kind of overhead there is with WebSockets. I looked around but couldn't find quite a clear answer. What I'm wondering is with every single coordinate packet sent from the server to client, how much overhead is there? Some places say only a couple bytes but then other sources say around 80 due to the TCP/IP header information.

Secondly, would it be a good idea to queue up all these coordinate packets and then send them out every couple seconds or so? The client would always be a couple seconds behind but every time they received a chunk, they would evenly space and play them out so it looked fluid.

Or maybe there is some other way to automatically buffer packets like this, or maybe it is not necessary for whatever other reason (overhead not as I as I think it is)?

**Edit:** Follow-up question: So if I do queue up messages, what is a good size to make them before sending them off (approx bytes)? I think that if they become too large I can have the opposite problem and the protocol would have to manually split them.

Comment: You can see the webSocket data packet format here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Step_2_Exchanging_Data_Frames.  The bandwidth consumption is probably not your issue.  The issue will be more the overhead with processing lots of tiny packets both in node.js and in your TCP stack.

Comment: jfriend00: Isn't this just the frame though? What about the packet containing it containing IP information and whatnot? I'm talking about the total bandwidth cost of sending one websocket message from server to client.

Comment: Yes, that is wrapped in a TCP packet if that's what you're talking about.  That's small also, but it does contribute some bytes.

Comment: Isn't "some" around 80 bytes? That's around 90% of the bandwidth, no?

Comment: I give up.  Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1):

whiteboard and "freehand / pencil / paint brush"  if just sending x,y data, i might encourage sending a x,y,time   time is for instead a sudden line is drawn, but instead gradually gets drawn.   you might look into www.npmjs.com and look up a "diff" library, if you plan on que up x,y,time

there is also some "diff" that handle differences between image formats. sending just differences between point a in time and point b in time.  dailup users = slow connection and get an update say every 2 to 120 seconds.  while a broadband connection gets updates every 1 to 10 seconds pending on there lag / latency.  broadband + high lag / latency = satellite users. folks in other countries (across oceans) = high lag.

if going purely following the mouse cursor, and left/right mouse button clicks, and sending some sort of ID of what menu button they clicked. and then dragging cursor around in the canvas area to quickly.  a dailup user could get behind quickly.  and queing on both (person currently drawing), server queing, and folks watching needs queing would be advised.

data sent out 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9  may come in as 1,3,5,4,2,6,7,9,8 as far as coming in and getting processed and in that you get the data, but not in expected order. resulting in scribbles vs a smooth line if just capturing x,y data of mouse.

think of games and lag. you are going along and suddenly "rubber banded" to a previous location. que'ing and dealing with a "roll back" time machine, and start re-drawing the white board from a previous time. would help deal with scribbles.

watching videos on internet and pausing video. and waiting for buffer / que to load up to a certain point, before playing movie.

tcp/ip = keeps from loosing data,  streams can allow for more info due to less overhead, but there can, and will be data loss with streams.

how important is every single little pixel in your whiteboard for your expected user base. say math class, and drawing some different symbols and numbers. or a quick drawing of writing via mouse and pencil / free hand icon. how complex will be the buttons, example "paint can/brush" aka squritter that randomly tosses dots as you move mouse. or when you zoom in, and dealing pixel per pixel (actually see box like outline of each pixel)

you might look for some "help desk" apps, were you give control to someone else and they can take over your mouse/keyboard and see what you see.   "conference" apps, most likely also have the que's and like built in as well.

are you going to setup a single "setting" and applied to everyone that is watching, or offer up individual settings per watcher? so as to adapt to there connection. if per individual, are you going to have server, have main que of who is drawing, and then per individual calculate what is best for each watcher? or is CPU limited such as smartphone, pda and like...

.........................

figure out some additional use case scenarios for your app. and build from there, even if not optimized, and once there, then start optimizing it. which may mean re-doing a good portion of the app.